# Congito Logout not working, still logged in

Tags: amazon-cognito

i'm trying to hit the logout endpoint within Congito, however I just get redirected back without being logged out.

I do not unset the refresh token within my app as I expect this token to be invalidated when i hit the logout endpoint, which would then cause the user to get redirected back to the login page when the refresh token fails.

This is how I redirect to the Congito logout endpoint:

```php
    public function logout(): void
    {
        $params = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'logout_uri' => 'https://localhost/',
        ]);
        resolve('app')->abort(301, '', ['Location' =>"https://{$this->domain}/logout?$params"]);
    }
```

My `logout_uri` is correct within my allowed signout urls within Cognito. And it has the `/` on the end too as I noticed some posts saying this caused an issue.

Any ideas?